# Find third point from two points on one line

Tags: geometry

suppose if we don't have distance and want to calculate third point the same line then what we have to do??? actually i have a software project related to this.So i have to use this equation in my system .. Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Do you have the equation of the line? There are an infinite number of points on that line. Pick one. Presumably you have some sort of criterion for picking that point. Use it.

Comment: sir, actually i am drawing the geometry in 3d space and i have two points(x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2) so i am using the equation :  x3 = x1 + dx*k and y3 = y1 + dy*k and same for z3 where dx = x2-x1, dy=y2-y1, dz=z2-z1. now i find the distance by d^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2. Now i add and subtract same value from distance and found the value of k by (dx^2 + dy^2)*k^2 = d^2. By using this method i am finding the value of X3, Y3, Z3. Is it a good method or complicated method?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the points in $d$-dimensional space
are $A$ and $B$,
then all points on the line
through $A$ and $B$
are of the form
$P(c)=A+c(B-A)$,
where the operations are done
componentwise.

If 
$A=(a_1, a_2, ..., a_d)$
and
$B=(b_1, b_2, ..., b_d)$,
then
$P(c) = (a_1+c(b_1-a_1), ..., a_d+c(b_d-a_d))$.

Note that when
$c=0$ this gives $A$
and when $c=1$ this gives $B$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two points on a line $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ the equation of the line is given by $y=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}(x-x_0)+y_0$, with $x_0 \neq x_1$.

So replace values, and use another $x$ to find a point on the line.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, but suppose if X0 = X1 then what will happened and i am drawing this geometry in 3d space so this equation will be the same in that case?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want any point on the line through $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, the easiest one to find is $(x_1+2(x_2-x_1),y_1+2(y_2-y_1),z_1+2(z_2-z_1))=(2x_2-x_1,2y_2-y_1,2z_2-z_1)$  It just extends the line from point $1$ to point $2$ by the same distance.  This works in any number of dimensions.